# Cannot read property '1' of undefined angular 7

Tags: angular, undefined, httpclient, angular7

I am making a cart component in angular.I used HttpClient for getting data from local server and stored it in products array. I used *ngFor to display data in html file .The data is shown properly in html but when I tried to access it in component file to calculate cart total it gives me this error.

[Cart displayed and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWypE.png)

Here is the code:

.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card shopping-cart">
        <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light row">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
             <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            Shopping cart
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="justR">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm pull-right ">Continue shopping</a>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
                <!-- PRODUCT -->
                <div *ngFor="let product of products;index as i">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{product.prodUrl}}" alt="prewiew" width="120" height="80">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 text-sm-center col-sm-12 text-md-left col-md-6">
                                    <h4 class="product-name"><strong>{{product.prodName}}</strong></h4>
                                    <h4>
                                        <small>{{product.prodDescription}}</small>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 text-sm-center col-md-4 text-md-right row">
                                    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-6 text-md-right" style="padding-top: 5px">
                                        <h6><strong>₹{{product.prodPrice}} <span class="text-muted">x</span></strong></h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="quantity">
                                            <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="products[i].prodQuantity" step="1" max="99" min="1" value="{{products[i].prodQuantity}}" title="Qty" class="qty" size="4">

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-right">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>


                </div>


        <div class="justR">
        <div class="pull-right">
                <a (click)="updateCart()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary pull-right">
                    Update shopping cart
                </a>
            </div>
 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="justR" style="margin: 10px">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Checkout</a>
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin: 5px">
             Total price: <b>{{total}}</b>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Cart } from 'src/app/cart/cartInterface';
import { RegisterService} from 'src/app/register.service';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-cart',
 templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
 })


 export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

private url='http://localhost:3000/getcdata';
public products:Cart[];
errorMessage = '';
total:number;
constructor(private http:HttpClient,private registerService:RegisterService) 
{}



ngOnInit()
{
  this.http.get<Cart[]>(this.url).subscribe(res => {
  this.products = res;
  },
  error => console.error(error));
  this.total=getTotal(this.products);
  console.log(this.products[1].prodName);
}

updateCart()
{
    this.registerService.update(this.products)
    .subscribe(
    (      data: { message: string; }) => { console.log(data.message)},
    (      error: { statusText: string; }) => this.errorMessage = 
    error.statusText,     
    );
 }

}

 function getTotal(items:Cart[])
 {
   var total:number;
   var i=0;
   for(var item in items)
    {
     total=total+(items[i].prodPrice*items[i].prodQuantity);
     i++;
    }
  return total;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the other stuff on ngOnInit into the callback like this:

```
    this.http.get<Cart[]>(this.url)
      .subscribe(res => {
        // This is called asynchronously when you get the response 
        this.products = res;
        this.total = getTotal(this.products);
        console.log(this.products[1].prodName);
      }, error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `console.log(this.products[1].prodName);` is the line throwing the error. Your `this.http.get<Cart[]>(this.url)` happens asynchronously and will run the code after it before running the callbacks inside the `subscribe`. Network requests (and other asynchronous things) take time and JavaScript was designed to handing asynchronous things by adding them to an event loop to be run later when they have finished and not block the rest of the code from executing.

So `this.total=getTotal(this.products);` and `console.log(this.products[1].prodName);` get run before `this.products = res;` is run causing `this.products` to be still be an empty array when you try to read the second element out of it.

Doing some reading about how asynchronous stuff works in JavaScript and how Promises, async/await, and/or Observables can be used to handle asynchronous things might be helpful (Angular seems to rely heavily on Observables). It can be a little confusing at first but you get used to handling async things.

Comment: Thanks, as you said it is called asynchronously, I will learn more.